# Error Messages Buried By Cyan note: Messages When Using GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm working on a c++ project for a class using gcc and it's not compiling, but that's not the problem.  The problem is I can't see the errors that are causing my code to fail because it gets buried underneath hundreds of cyan `note:` messages. After a certain point the terminal history cuts off and I can't scroll up any further.  Is there a way I can move the important errors to the bottom?

Thanks, and sorry for asking a probably dumb question.

Comment: You needn't rely on terminal history: `gcc file.c 2>&1 |less`

Comment: You could redirect the compile output to a file. What do these `note:` messages say? Never seen them myself before.